# Get all listitems in the listbox using JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to get all the listitems that exist in a listbox using jquery, it does not matter if selected or not.

Here is my client side script:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelected" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="10">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Employee_OID">EID</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="EmpID">Emp ID</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Employee_Name">Name</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Since you are using the traditional .Net (runat="server"), be careful about the timeframe of your data.  Implementing this as others have suggested will only be good "POST" FACTO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding a static ID (ClientIDMode="Static") generation to the ListBox, you could use the ID property value in jQuery directly (skipping ClientID usage):

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelected" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="10" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Employee_OID">EID</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="EmpID">Emp ID</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Employee_Name">Name</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

**jQuery to get all options:**

```
$('#lstSelected option')
```

**jQuery to get all selected options:**

```
$('#lstSelected option:selected')
```

See more info here on the ClientIDMode: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: That did the trick...I need the values and text in csv format..any help on that?

Comment: There are better answers for this if you search stackoverflow, but look into the .val() and .text() methods to get the value and text of options. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880293/jquery-get-remaining-option-values-in-csv-format

Answer (score 1):

To get the element client side you're going to need to use the `ClientID` property of the `ListBox`:

**All Options**

```
$("#<%=lstSelected.ClientID %> option");
```

**All Selected Options**

```
$("#<%=lstSelected.ClientID %> option:selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to comment on neurotix's answer cause of reputation.. wanted to share though this worked for me just needed to put $() around "this".

```
$('#lstSelected option').each(function(){


if($(this).val() == anyvalue)

//your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick:

```
$('#lstSelected option').each(function(){


if(this.val() == anyvalue)

//your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%= lstSelected.ClientID %>").find("option");
```